# What emoji characters are supported in Jira's Quick Filters?

Tags: emoji, jira

I notice that when I create a Quick Filter with some emoji (e.g. ☺️) it saves, but when I try others (e.g. ) it doesn't save.

Which emoji characters does Jira support in the Quick Filters?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Based on my manual research, I think I found a pattern. It seems only the 2-byte characters in the [range U+203C through U+3299](https://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm) are supported. This includes the [Miscellaneous Symbols Unicode block (U+2600-U+26FF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols).

> U+203C-U+3299
>   ‼️⁉️™️ℹ️↔️↕️↖️↗️↘️↙️↩️↪️⌚️⌛️⌨️⏏️⏩⏪⏫⏬⏭⏮⏯⏰⏱⏲⏳⏸⏹⏺Ⓜ️▪️▫️▶️◀️◻️◼️◽️◾️☀️☁️☂️☃️☄️☎️☑️☔️☕️☘️☝️☠️☢️☣️☦️☪️☮️☯️☸️☹️☺️♀♂♈️♉️♊️♋️♌️♍️♎️♏️♐️♑️♒️♓️♠️♣️♥️♦️♨️♻️♿️⚒⚓️⚔️⚕︎⚖️⚗️⚙️⚛️⚜️⚠️⚡️⚪️⚫️⚰️⚱️⚽️⚾️⛄️⛅️⛈⛎⛏⛑⛓⛔️⛩⛪️⛰⛱⛲️⛳️⛴⛵️⛷⛸⛹️‍♀️⛺️⛽️✂️✅✈️✉️✊✋✌️✍️✏️✒️✔️✖️✝️✡️✨✳️✴️❄️❇️❌❎❓❔❕❗️❣️❤️➕➖➗➡️➰➿⤴️⤵️⬅️⬆️⬇️⬛️⬜️⭐️⭕️〰️〽️㊗️㊙️

> U+0023,U+20E3-U+0039,U+20E3
>    #️⃣*️⃣0️⃣1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣

---

There didn't seem to be any pattern with which emoji characters are and aren't supported, so I wrote a simple cliclick command to copy and paste emojis from TextEdit.

These are (some of) the emoji characters that work in Jira's Quick Filter:

> ListA:
>
> ♓️♒️♑️♐️♏️♎️♍️♌️♋️♊️♉️♈️⛎☦️☯️✡️☸️☪️✝️☮️❣️❤️✏️✒️✂️✉️⚗️⚱️⚰️⚔️⛓⚙️⛏⚒⚖️⏳⌛️⏱⏰☎️⏲⌨️⌚️☔️❄️⛄️☃️⛈☁️⛅️☀️☄️⚡️⭐️☘️✨☂️⛑✍️✋✌️☝️✊☠️☹️☺️
>   ⏩⏮⏭⏺⏹⏯⏸▶️*️⃣#️⃣9️⃣8️⃣7️⃣6️⃣5️⃣4️⃣3️⃣2️⃣1️⃣0️⃣ℹ️♿️Ⓜ️❎✳️❇️✅♻️⚜️⚠️〽️⁉️‼️❔❓❕❗️♨️⛔️⭕️❌㊗️㊙️✴️☣️☢️⚛️
>   ♦️♥️♣️♠️⬜️◻️◼️◽️◾️▫️▪️⚫️⚪️☑️✔️➿➰〰️cc™️✖️➗➖➕⤵️↩️⤴️↪️↔️↕️↖️↙️↘️↗️⬇️⬆️⬅️➡️◀️⏬⏫⏪

I tried [pasting a bunch of emoji characters](https://getemoji.com) into Jira to see which work. The majority of them didn't work. Only the above worked. For reference, here are the ones I tried:

> ListB:
>
> ☺️                             ☹️                                             ☠️                      ✊    ✌️       ☝️ ✋        ✍️                     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ️‍♀️ ️ ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️     ‍♂️ ‍♀️  ‍♀️      ‍❤️‍ ‍❤️‍  ‍❤️‍‍ ‍❤️‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍                 ⛑         ☂️
>
> ☘️                                   ⭐️  ✨ ⚡️   ☄️ ☀️  ⛅️    ☁️  ⛈   ☃️ ⛄️ ❄️        ☔️
>
> ⌚️    ⌨️                   ☎️        ⏱ ⏲ ⏰  ⌛️ ⏳                 ⚖️   ⚒  ⛏  ⚙️ ⛓     ⚔️   ⚰️ ⚱️     ⚗️                               ✉️                                                       ️   ️‍ ✂️   ✒️    ✏️
>
> ❤️       ❣️         ☮️ ✝️ ☪️  ☸️ ✡️   ☯️ ☦️  ⛎ ♈️ ♉️ ♊️ ♋️ ♌️ ♍️ ♎️ ♏️ ♐️ ♑️ ♒️ ♓️  ⚛️  ☢️ ☣️    ️   ️ ✴️    ㊙️ ㊗️     ️ ️   ️  ❌ ⭕️  ⛔️     ♨️        ❗️ ❕ ❓ ❔ ‼️ ⁉️   〽️ ⚠️   ⚜️  ♻️ ✅ ️  ❇️ ✳️ ❎   Ⓜ️     ♿️ ️  ️              ℹ️          0️⃣ 1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣ 5️⃣ 6️⃣ 7️⃣ 8️⃣ 9️⃣   #️⃣ *️⃣ ▶️ ⏸ ⏯ ⏹ ⏺ ⏭ ⏮ ⏩ ⏪ ⏫ ⏬ ◀️   ➡️ ⬅️ ⬆️ ⬇️ ↗️ ↘️ ↙️ ↖️ ↕️ ↔️ ↪️ ↩️ ⤴️ ⤵️        ➕ ➖ ➗ ✖️  c ™️ c©️ ®️c 〰️ ➰c➿  c   ✔️ ☑️  ⚪️ ⚫️           ▪️ ▫️ ◾️ ◽️ ◼️ ◻️ ⬛️ ⬜️         ‍    ♠️ ♣️ ♥️ ♦️   ️

*Disclaimer: The mechanism to determine if a character is supported or isn't supported involved a flaky script that copied each emoji character and tried saving it. At times there were flaws while copying, or delays while saving. Therefore, while all the items in ListA do work in Jira, there may be a few emoji characters in ListB that also work in Jira.*

---

To run the script yourself, download [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/), then do the following:

1. Put JIRA window on the top left.
2. Navigate to the Quick Filters edit page in Jira.
3. Put TextEdit window on the right.
4. Paste Emojis from https://getemoji.com into TextEdit.
5. Place the carat in TextEdit at the start of the file.
6. Run the command:

   ```
   ./cliclick c:1000,35 w:100 kd:shift kp:arrow-right ku:shift kd:cmd t:c ku:cmd kp:arrow-right kp:arrow-right c:340,355 w:100 c:340,355 kd:cmd t:a t:v ku:cmd kp:return w:200
   ```
7. Copy everything after `c:1000,35` as many times as you want if you want to copy more than one emoji at a time. For example, to run it 3 times:

   ```
   ./cliclick c:1000,35 w:100 kd:shift kp:arrow-right ku:shift kd:cmd t:c ku:cmd kp:arrow-right kp:arrow-right c:340,355 w:100 c:340,355 kd:cmd t:a t:v ku:cmd kp:return w:200 c:1000,35 w:100 kd:shift kp:arrow-right ku:shift kd:cmd t:c ku:cmd kp:arrow-right kp:arrow-right c:340,355 w:100 c:340,355 kd:cmd t:a t:v ku:cmd kp:return w:200 c:1000,35 w:100 kd:shift kp:arrow-right ku:shift kd:cmd t:c ku:cmd kp:arrow-right kp:arrow-right c:340,355 w:100 c:340,355 kd:cmd t:a t:v ku:cmd kp:return w:200
   ```

The command will do the following:

1. `c:1000,32 w:100` - Click on TextEdit which is located at position (1000,35)
2. `kd:shift kp:arrow-right ku:shift` - Highlight the next emoji character.
3. `kd:cmd t:c ku:cmd` - Copy it to the clipboard (Note: this is necessary because `t:` does not work in cliclick)
4. `kp:arrow-right kp:arrow-right` - Place the carat at the start of the next emoji.
5. `c:340,355 w:100 c:340,355` - Click in the Jira Quick Filter title field. Clicking twice is necessary to be less flaky.
6. `kd:cmd t:a t:v ku:cmd` - Select all the text in there, then paste the emoji.
7. `kp:return w:200` - Try submitting this Quick Filter with only the title, and wait 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Open browser console and paste following code:

```
let icons = document.getElementsByClassName('chars');
let allowed = [];
for(let i = 0; i < icons.length - 1; i++){
    if(icons[i].innerText.length <= 1){
        allowed.push(icons[i].innerText);
        icons[i].style.border = "thick solid red";
    }     
}
console.log(...allowed);
```

☺ ☹ ☠ ❣ ❤ ✋ ✌ ☝ ✊ ✍ ⛷ ⛹ ☘ ☕ ⛰ ⛪ ⛩ ⛲ ⛺ ♨ ⛽ ⚓ ⛵ ⛴ ✈ ⌛ ⏳ ⌚ ⏰ ⏱ ⏲ ☀ ⭐ ☁ ⛅ ⛈ ☂ ☔ ⛱ ⚡ ❄ ☃ ⛄ ☄ ✨ ⚽ ⚾ ⛳ ⛸ ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♟ ⛑ ☎ ⌨ ✉ ✏ ✒ ✂ ⛏ ⚒ ⚔ ⚙ ⚖ ⛓ ⚗ ⚰ ⚱ ♿ ⚠ ⛔ ☢ ☣ ⬆ ↗ ➡ ↘ ⬇ ↙ ⬅ ↖ ↕ ↔ ↩ ↪ ⤴ ⤵ ⚛ ✡ ☸ ☯ ✝ ☦ ☪ ☮ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ⛎ ▶ ⏩ ⏭ ⏯ ◀ ⏪ ⏮ ⏫ ⏬ ⏸ ⏹ ⏺ ⏏ ♀ ♂ ⚧ ✖ ➕ ➖ ➗ ♾ ‼ ⁉ ❓ ❔ ❕ ❗ 〰 ⚕ ♻ ⚜ ⭕ ✅ ☑ ✔ ❌ ❎ ➰ ➿ 〽 ✳ ✴ ❇ © ® ™ ℹ Ⓜ ㊗ ㊙ ⚫ ⚪ ⬛ ⬜ ◼ ◻ ◾ ◽ ▪ ▫v